# SMC: Is there a way to control two sliding surfaces with just one control input?

Tags: control, quadcopter, flight-controller

This is a question related to Control Systems.

I've been searching papers all over the internet with very little success. I know that traditionally we want one control per sliding surface but If anyone has any papers in how to do something like this I'd appreciate it.

UPDATE: If anyone wants context, I'm doing a project about guiding a helicopter/drone into its final landing position (Not doing the descent). It goes straight into the final position without making any turns. Pretty straightforward. The problem is that I have two sliding surfaces. This is its trajectory:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I0l5hrMvcyCqEIWbN7Ya_Pnfy8dOnqOL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @tadm123 please edit your question to explain your problem more fully. It's not clear what you're defining as a "sliding surface". Are you talking about the two skids of the vehicle that are coupled? Are there 6 full degrees of freedom in the system? I don't know that I agree with your baseline assumption that "traditionally we want one control per sliding surface", for a fully actuated system you need 3 degrees of control per unconstrained surface. In addition to clarifying your system, please also clarify your goals of control. An under-actuated system can reach some goals but not others.